# Get name per specified type in controller

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have an API that gets data from database. The sample data that I'm getting looks like this:

```
 [
    {
        "Name": "Bar1",
        "Type": "Bar",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pie1",
        "Type": "Pie",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pie2",
        "Type": "Pie",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Line1",
        "Type": "Line",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pie3",
        "Type": "Pie",
    },

]
```

I want to get all the names that belong to type=Pie and assign it on an $scope array and then put it on ng-repeat. How can I possibly do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement can be easily fulfilled by `ng-repeat` and `filter` on view side, there is no need for additional operation in controller side.

Follow the below step:

In controller define like follows:

```
$scope.items = [{
        "Name": "Bar1",
        "Type": "Bar",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pie1",
        "Type": "Pie",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pie2",
        "Type": "Pie",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Line1",
        "Type": "Line",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pie3",
        "Type": "Pie",
    },

];
```

Please use the following in Html:

```
<div ng-controller = "YOUR_CONTROLLER">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { type: 'pie'}">
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get array of names only, check this. You can further assign this array to $scope variable and use in ng-repeat

First use filter to get filtered data and then select name from it.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "Name": "Bar1",
        "Type": "Bar",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pie1",
        "Type": "Pie",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pie2",
        "Type": "Pie",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Line1",
        "Type": "Line",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pie3",
        "Type": "Pie",
    },

]

let names = data.filter(d => d.Type === 'Pie').map(m => m.Name)

console.log(names)
```